# How do I disable download in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Is there any start up flag for disabling downloads?

For example, when I go to `www.example.com/file.zip`, a file is downloaded, which I do not wish to.

How can we avoid this?

Comment: That URL is directed to a file (file.zip), not a webpage, therefore it's expected any browser to try to download the file. Perhaps you want to go www.example.com instead?

Comment: Is your goal to actually disable all downloads (so it is impossible to download anything), or to just ensure that a download isn't initiated immediately upon arriving at any URL?

Comment: One option that Chrome users have is to disable automatic downloads in the web browser.

1, Load chrome://settings/ in the browser's address bar.
2, Scroll down and click on the "show advanced settings" link.
3, Scroll down to the Downloads section.
4, Check the preference "Ask where to save each file before downloading".

Chrome will prompt you for a download location each time a download is initiated in the browser.

Comment: I do not know why this question was asked, but I want the answer because I'm running chromium in kiosk mode and want to prevent users from overwriting files which I have to keep writable.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I disable download in google chrome?

> **Prevent users from downloading files**
>
> Supported on Chrome 61 and later.
>
> As an administrator, you can specify whether users can download files
> from the Internet using Google Chrome. For example, you might want to
> let users download files but block any that are dangerous, such as
> malware. If users try to download dangerous files, Google Safe
> Browsing shows them a security warning that they can’t bypass.
>
> **Apply policy to users**
>
> To apply restrictions to downloads, configure the
> [DownloadRestrictions](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/) policy.
>
> You can restrict downloads that are triggered on webpages when users
> click a download link on the page, or right-click a file and choose
> Save link as....
>
> Restrictions don’t apply when users save the currently displayed
> webpage. To save a webpage, users can:
>
> - Click File and then Save Page as…, or
> - Click Print and choose Save as PDF for the destination.
>
> **Download restriction options**
>
> You can specify the type of downloads that Google Chrome will block,
> depending on how secure they are.
>
> - 0 (No special restrictions) — Downloads go through the usual security restrictions based on Safe Browsing analysis results.
> - 1 (Block dangerous downloads) — Downloads are allowed, except for those that carry Safe Browsing warnings.
> - 2 (Block potentially dangerous downloads) — Downloads are allowed, except for those that carry Safe Browsing warnings of
>   potentially dangerous downloads.
> - **3 (Block all downloads) — All downloads are blocked.**

Source [Prevent users from downloading files - Chrome for enterprise Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7579271?hl=en)

> **DownloadRestrictions**
>
> Allow download restrictions
>
> Data type:
>
> ```
> Integer [Windows:REG_DWORD]
> ```
>
> Windows registry location for Windows clients:
>
> ```
> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\DownloadRestrictions
> ```
>
> Windows registry location for Google Chrome OS clients:
>
> ```
> Software\Policies\Google\ChromeOS\DownloadRestrictions
> ```
>
> Mac/Linux preference name:
>
> ```
> DownloadRestrictions
> ```
>
> Supported on:
>
> - Google Chrome (Linux, Mac, Windows) since version 61
> - Google Chrome OS (Google Chrome OS) since version 61
>
> Supported features:
>
> ```
> Can Be Recommended: Yes, Dynamic Policy Refresh: Yes, Per Profile: Yes
> ```
>
> Description:
>
> - Configures the type of downloads that Google Chrome will completely block, without letting users override the security
>   decision.
> - If you set this policy, Google Chrome will prevent certain types of downloads, and won't let user bypass the security warnings.
> - When the 'Block dangerous downloads' option is chosen, all downloads are allowed, except for those that carry SafeBrowsing
>   warnings.
> - When the 'Block potentially dangerous downloads' option is chosen, all downloads allowed, except for those that carry
>   SafeBrowsing warnings of potentially dangerous downloads.
> - When the 'Block all downloads' option is chosen, all downloads are blocked.
> - When this policy is not set, (or the 'No special restrictions' option is chosen), the downloads will go through the usual security
>   restrictions based on SafeBrowsing analysis results.
> - Note that these restrictions apply to downloads triggered from web page content, as well as the 'download link...' context menu
>   option. These restrictions do not apply to the save / download of the
>   currently displayed page, nor does it apply to saving as PDF from the
>   printing options.
> - See https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing for more info on SafeBrowsing.
> - ```
>      0 = No special restrictions
>   ```
> - ```
>      1 = Block dangerous downloads
>   ```
> - ```
>      2 = Block potentially dangerous downloads
>   ```
> - ```
>      3 = Block all downloads
>   ```
>
> Example value:
>
> ```
> 0x00000002 (Windows), 2 (Linux), 2 (Mac)
> ```

Source [Policy List - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DownloadRestrictions)